# How to add RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} in the specific loop

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following htaccess code:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} 11A465|Ahrefs|ArchiveBot|AspiegelBot|Baiduspider|bingbot|BLEXBot|Bytespider|CCBot|Curebot|Daum|Detectify|DotBot|Grapeshot|heritrix|Kinza|LieBaoFast|Linguee|LMY47V|MauiBot|Mb2345Browser|MegaIndex|MicroMessenger|MJ12bot|MQQBrowser|PageFreezer|PiplBot|Riddler|Screaming.Frog|Search365bot|SearchBlox|Seekport|SemanticScholarBot|SemrushBot|SEOkicks|serpstatbot|Siteimprove.com|Sogou.web.spider|trendictionbot|TurnitinBot|UCBrowser|weborama-fetcher|Vagabondo|VelenPublicWebCrawler|YandexBot|YisouSpider [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

This code blocks direct access to " **/?s=** " based on the listed user agents detection.

Now, I would like to implement `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/search` to this code, so that it works for " **/search/** " as well.

In other words - if bots try to access " **/?s=** " OR " **/search/** " - they get blocked.

I was able to make this work for /search/ or for /?s= but never for both at the same time, which is my goal.

Original code snippet link: https://support.acquia.com/hc/en-us/articles/360042181273-Block-Access-to-Bad-Bots-coming-from-the-Huawei-Cloud

Here is the screenshot that might give you more insight in what is happening and what I'm trying to accomplish.

[image]

Comment: _“This code blocks direct access to " /?s= " based on the listed user agents detection.”_ - where are you imagining _any_ limitation to the query string containing `?s=` here? I don’t see any.

Comment: This is the code snippet I found online, it is not specific to ?s= but it works like that by default. This is the original link: https://support.acquia.com/hc/en-us/articles/360042181273-Block-Access-to-Bad-Bots-coming-from-the-Huawei-Cloud

Comment: In addition, from the original article: "BLOCKS only when search arguments are present like /news/feed?search=XXX or /rss?page=21" So I guess it is done via RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ?

Comment: `%{QUERY_STRING} .` only demands that the query string contains at least one character. Instead of that, you will need two RewriteConds for this – one that checks if the query string actually begins with `?s=`, and one that checks if the requested URI path started with `search/`. You will need to join those with an explicit OR, but since AND is implicit, you might need to repeat the condition that checks the user agent a second time.